# System time synchronized with the hardware clock

Tags: time, windows-server-2016, clock, timedrift

From the last 2 months, we are facing below issue on our Windows 2016 server every 10 days.

Server time is going back by 1 hour with the below message in eventvwr.

```
The system time has changed to ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T07:34:29.500000000Z from ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T08:34:38.153992100Z.
Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
```

It is again getting corrected after 2 hours.

```
The system time has changed to ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T09:34:29.500000000Z from ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T08:34:29.508436400Z.
Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
```

Below are the default settings of the server since very long time.

- 'Set Time Automatically' is off in 'Date & Time settings'.
- StartUp type of Windows Time service is  Manual(Trigger) and is not running.
  This is a WorkGroup server & not joined to any domain.

How can we avoid the system time being synchronized with the hardware clock.

Comment: Is your timezone set correctly?

Comment: Server is in US. But, we want the timezone to be different i.e. UTC+4  & this required timezone is set. Dont see any issues with the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the hardware clock, run the following command:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation" /v RealTimeIsUniversal /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

This will add a registry key to ignore the clock, by doing this
you will be using the internet time server.

Comment: Hi Harry. Thanks for your response. Internet time server is not running. We do not want it to be synced with the Internet Time server as well. Could you kindly help me understand why the TimeZoneInformation needs to be modified when we want to disable synchronization with hardware clock. Thank you.

Comment: This is where the hardware clock settings are stored. Try to see if the above registry change helps. I don't really know what Windows will do after this change in the case that the Internet time server is also disabled.